# "Perfect" solutions to the kissing number problem besides in dimensions 1,2,8, and 24.

Tags: geometry, spheres, combinatorial-geometry, packing-problem

The kissing number problem asks how many n dimensional unit spheres can fit around a central one with no overlapping; a natural question is in what dimensions can this be done so that there is no extra space to move any outer sphere around the central one, as in the following picture:

[image]

There are such configurations in dimensions 1, 2, 8, and 24, and they tie into some exceptional mathematics. My question is, is it possible there are other dimensions that also exhibit this property? Which dimensions have been ruled out, and if little is known, are there natural conjectures or heuristics?

Comment: This is a difficult problem in mathematics. There are some details on [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03631.pdf).

Comment: It seems they discuss bounds and such, but never raise the question if "perfection" like the Leech lattice can be obtained in higher dimensions

Comment: I'm not personally aware of any work that tries to determine whether a dimension contains a "perfect" lattice of the sort exemplified by the Leech lattice, without actually identifying that lattice.  An existence proof, so to speak.  The exact value of $\kappa(24)$ was obtained after the Leech lattice was explicitly known, wasn't it?

Comment: For some of the dimensions, it is known (from other work) that there are non-lattice packings that are better than any lattice packing, and I expect that for these, there is not likely to be an "unexpectedly" exact result like we have for $8$ and $24$ dimensions.  As you seem to be aware, dimensions $3$ and $4$ don't exhibit these "perfect" lattices either, and we only know their exact values because of the Delsarte approach and Musin's extension thereto.  Unfortunately, applying Musin's extension requires more hand-tuning as we move into higher dimensions—perhaps prohibitively more.

Comment: An interesting historical overview can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/notices/200408/comm-cass.pdf); from the same issue of *Notices of the AMS* can be found [this longer article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200408/fea-pfender.pdf) describing, in some detail, the Delsarte approach and Musin's extension.